# Bootstrap 3 Carousel Not initializing in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-8, carousel

I am using Bootstrap v3.3.2.  The carousel is not starting on IE8.  It shows all 4 panels I am using, unhidden, stacked on top of each other.  No animations.  The buttons do not work.

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="container" style="padding: 0;">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding: 0;">

                <div id="main-slideshow-container">

                    <div id="main-slideshow-container-inner">
                        <div id="main-slideshow" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="@INTERVAL@">


                          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                          <div class="carousel-inner">
                            // @PANELS@
                          </div>


                          <!-- Controls -->
                          <a class="left carousel-control" role="button" 
                             data-slide="prev" onclick="$('#main-slideshow').carousel('prev');">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                          </a>
                          <a class="right carousel-control" role="button" 
                             data-slide="next" onclick="$('#main-slideshow').carousel('next');">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                          </a>


                        </div> <!-- Carousel -->
                    </div>



                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#main-slideshow").carousel();
    }); 
</script>
```

In my header I load the `bootstrap` CSS files, then `jquery` 1.11.0.  Then `bootstrap` js.  Then this last:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src='/bootstrap/js/html5shiv.js'></script>
        <script src='/bootstrap/js/respond.min.js'></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue, but the shiv should be included after any stylesheets, but before any other javascript.

Comment: @dave  Thanks.  I tried that, but didn't seem to change much,

Answer (score 1):

"Internet Explorer 8 and 9 are also supported, however, please be aware that some CSS3 properties and HTML5 elements are not fully supported by these browsers."

Quote from getbootstrap.com

[image]

[image]

May this be your problem? Reply if you've still got a problem!

Comment: Don't think this is the issue.  All of these css commands should be handled in the default bootstrap files.  I have not added these items on top of what they would be doing.  Unless what they are doing is wrong.

Comment: i'm downloading bootstrap now to test your webpage.

Comment: Well, it DOES use transition but that should not break the code if it is not supported, right?  According to their docs, they simply do not have fallbacks. It just means there is no fancy animations between panels.